# CSS flex-wrap property: When does wrapping begin?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

In the following example I am using percent values in the `flex-basis` property. What makes the browser decide when to start breaking the row?

```css
section {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

div {
  border: 1px solid;
  padding: 1rem;
  flex: 1 0 10%;
}

body {
  margin: 100px;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
  <div>5</div>
  <div>6</div>
  <div>7</div>
  <div>8</div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First, the browser determines the width of the container.

(For these examples, I'll assume `flex-direction: row`, but the same logic applies to `column`.)

Let's say the width has a computed value of 800px.

You have 8 flex items with a width of 10%. So each item is 80px.

Notes:

- Because you are using a percentage length, these items *will not* wrap, even with `flex-wrap: wrap`. Why? Because 10% is relative to the container width, and as the parent shrinks so does the child. [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/bu4a97vh/4/)
- If you tell the flex items to grow as much as possible (`flex-grow: 1`), they will still not wrap, even with `flex-wrap: wrap`, for the same reason as above. [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/bu4a97vh/5/)
- However, once you introduce `border`, `padding` or `margin` to the equation, these lengths add to the 10%, and the line of flex items will exceed the width of the container. Now the items will wrap.

  - [Border DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/bu4a97vh/6/)
  - [Padding DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/bu4a97vh/7/)
  - [Margin DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/bu4a97vh/8/)
- The reason borders and padding force a wrap is the default box model: `box-sizing: content-box`, which calculates borders and padding in addition to width (`flex-basis`). However, by changing the box model to `border-box`, the width will include borders and padding, and wrapping can be avoided. [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/bu4a97vh/9/)

  Note that if borders and/or padding are sizable enough, they may still force a wrap even with `border-box`. [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/bu4a97vh/10/).

  Note that margins will cause wrapping in either box model because they're always outside the width calculation.

  ([Read more about the CSS `box-sizing` property.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing))
- When using absolute lengths, such as pixels, the wrapping calculation is pretty straightforward. In the simplest terms, let's say we have 8 flex items, each with a width of 100px. These items will fit perfectly in the 800px container.

  Wrapping will occur the moment:

  - The container shrinks to 799px.
  - Margin is applied.
  - Border or padding is applied, in the `content-box` box model.
  - (Essentially, as the flex items are fixed-width, as soon as 1px is added to the line, or 1px is removed from the container, wrapping begins.)

This is a general explanation of wrapping in flex containers. There are other factors that can influence the breakpoint, such as `flex-shrink`.

Comment: When u say Let's say the width has a computed value of 800px - do you mean from explicitly value in the CSS or even computed value by the browser ( when no width defined )?

Comment: The latter. There's always a width to the container, whether you define it or not. I'm talking about the width the browser uses after it has finished parsing the CSS.

Comment: So why in this example they do wrap when you resize the screen? https://jsfiddle.net/qLgzhnj2/

Comment: Because of the padding, which computes to 32px per item. As I mentioned in my answer, if the padding is sizable enough, items will still wrap with or without `border-box`.

Comment: Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 1):

In your example above, the total width of each div is the sum of its border, padding, and content.

Each div has a 1px border on each side, a 1rem padding on each side, and its width is 10% of the container width as set in the flex declaration.

So its total width = 10% + 2rem + 2px.

And of course, the browser will try to fit as many divs on one line as it can.  When it can't fit any more, it will start a new line.

Comment: And if the box-sizing is border-box? the total width is 10% and it in percent so why it does not shrink when the size is in percent?